# Image to take the height and with of parent element

Tags: flutter

so today i did good with advancing in learning to make an app with flutter , i made a ListView , but the image didnt take the full height and with of the parent element , i tried some solutions but it didnt workout

this is the class

```
class FlowersItem extends StatelessWidget {

  final String imgAssetPath;

  FlowersItem({this.imgAssetPath});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
     width: 200,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xff29404E),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
        Column(children: <Widget>[
            ClipRect(
                child: FittedBox(
  child:    Image.asset(imgAssetPath),
  fit: BoxFit.fill,

),
       )
        ],)


        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

List<FlowersItem> flowers = [
 FlowersItem(
  imgAssetPath: 'assets/images/flower1.jpeg',

  ),
FlowersItem(
   imgAssetPath: 'assets/images/flower-pot.png',

  ),
FlowersItem(
     imgAssetPath: 'assets/images/flower-pot.png',
  ),
  FlowersItem(
      imgAssetPath: 'assets/images/flower-pot.png',
  ),
FlowersItem(
     imgAssetPath: 'assets/images/flower-pot.png',

  ),
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `BoxFit.cover`? I think that's what you are looking for.
It generally works for me when I want to fill out and entire box with an image.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `Expanded` class?

So, `Expanded` class is A widget that expands a child of a Row, Column, or Flex so that the child fills the available space.

you could find the documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html).